# BitmapImage throws an initialization exception when file does not exist

Tags: c#, wpf

I have XAMl like this

```
<Image x:Name="MyImage">
    <Image.Source>
        <BitmapImage UriSource="{Binding FullPhotoPath}"   CacheOption="OnLoad" />
    </Image.Source>
</Image>
```

This works fine so long as FullPhotoPath exists. if it does not then it throws an exception of

> Initialization of 'System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage' threw an exception.

I realize I can use just the Image tag

To show an image and if it doesn't exist then nothing is displayed (and no exception is thrown), but as far as I can tell this syntax does not allow me to use a `CacheOption`.

How can I show nothing if the image path does not exist?

Comment: have you tried handle exception in the code behind file? xaml doesn't support this feature

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a converter to create your BitmapImage with whatever settings you need which can also just return null if you see that the file doesn't exist and then just bind the Image.Source through the converter.

```
public class PathToBitmapImagelConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        string path = value as string;

        if (path == null || !File.Exists(path))
            return null;

        var bmp =  new BitmapImage();
        bmp.BeginInit();
        bmp.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
        bmp.UriSource = new Uri(path, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
        bmp.EndInit();
        return bmp;
    }


    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Make the converter accessible somewhere

```
<local:PathToBitmapImagelConverter x:Key="PathToBitmapImagelConverter"/>
```

Then use in your XAML like

```
<Image x:Name="MyImage" Source="{Binding FullPhotoPath, Converter={StaticResource PathToBitmapImagelConverter}}"/>
```

Comment: Nice, I'll try the converter and let you know

Comment: Awesome. One hangup though is that by setting the CacheOption in this way it does not actually get set. It stays as `Default`. I needed to use `BeginInit`/`EndInit` for it to take effect. I'm going to edit your answer if you don't mind.