# BitmapImage exception

Tags: wpf, xaml

Here is my XAML code:

```
<Image Stretch="Fill" Margin="15,0,0,0" ToolTip="{Binding ImagePath}" Width="110" Height="100" >
  <Image.Source>
   <BitmapImage RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="LowQuality" CacheOption="OnLoad" DecodePixelWidth="200" CreateOptions="IgnoreColorProfile" UriSource="{Binding ImagePath ,FallbackValue={StaticResource Lost},TargetNullValue={StaticResource Lost}}"/>
  </Image.Source>
</Image>
```

This is giving me this error:

> An unhandled exception of type
>   'System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException' occurred in
>   PresentationFramework.dll
>
> Additional information: Initialization of
>   'System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage' threw an exception.

Some times UriSource get null or invalid path that time i want to display default image

Comment: Look at the inner exception.  Unfortunately, almost anything that goes wrong during the initialization of a WPF application shows up as "XamlParseException" so you have to look at the InnerException to see what really happened.

Comment: I can understand what is really happened, here Image path does not contain data that is problem, So that time I want to display default image. how can set default image?

Answer (score 0):

[BitmapImage throws an initialization exception when file does not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29380410/bitmapimage-throws-an-initialization-exception-when-file-does-not-exist)

This answer worked for me, for the same problem you were having. I was able to return the image I wanted using a converter if the image file was missing.